# How to select all elements with a specific name under every li node with the same structure?

Tags: html, xpath, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a certain bunch of XPath locators that hold the elements I want to extract, and they have a similar structure:

```
/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/a
/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/a
/div/ul/li[3]/div/div[2]/a
...
```

They are actually simplified from Pixiv user page. Each `/div/div[2]/a` element has a title string, so they are actually artwork titles.

I want to use a single expression to fetch all the above `a` elements in an WebExtension called PageProbe. Although I've tried a bunch of methods, it just can't return the wanted result.

However, the following expression does return all the `a` elements, including the ones I don't need.

```
/div/
```

The following expression returns the `a` element under only the first `li` item.

```
/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/a
```

Sorry for not providing enough info earlier. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you gave here you can simply use this xpath:

```
/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/a
```

however I'm quite sure it should be some better locator based on other attributes like class names etc.

Comment: Tried this one but it returns only the first li `a` element instead of all.

Comment: Where do you use these locators? With selenium?

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough info. I use these in an WebExtension called PageProbe. I'm not sure whether it's selenium or not.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with that tool. Anyway, it should be a command to select multiple elements matching the same locator. for what you shown in the question my XPath will match all those elements. But if you are using a command to find single element it will bring you a first matching element.